# Getting data from a shared iCloud ical using java script

Tags: javascript, php

Iv started a project using javascript to get data from ical then parse it to a display in a list, however the code that is provided dose not work and I'm left with no data being displayed. I don't know anything about javascript which has left me in a position of not knowing what to do next. Any help getting this working would be very appreciated.

Basically nothing is being displayed when run and I'm not sure where to start in trying to debug this howe do I check to see if the data is being called or not?

I have three files which I'm working from.

calendar.php

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://p01-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/1/n6x7Farxpt7m9S8bHg1TGArSj7J6kanm_2KEoJPL5YIAk3y70FpRo4GyWwO-6QfHSY5mXtHcRGVxYZUf7U3HPDOTG5x0qYnno1Zr_VuKH2M';
    echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Magic Mirror</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <?php include('css/main.css') ?>
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/weather-icons.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gitHash = '<?php echo trim(`git rev-parse HEAD`) ?>';
    </script>
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="top left"><div class="date small dimmed"></div><div class="time"></div><div class="calendar xxsmall"></div></div>
    <div class="top right"><div class="windsun small dimmed"></div><div class="temp"></div><div class="forecast small dimmed"></div></div>
    <div class="center-ver center-hor"><div class="dishwasher light">Vaatwasser is klaar!</div></div>
    <div class="lower-third center-hor"><div class="compliment light"></div></div>
    <div class="bottom center-hor"><div class="news medium"></div></div>

</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.feedToJSON.js"></script>
<script src="js/ical_parser.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment-with-langs.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script src="js/rrule.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js?nocache=<?php echo md5(microtime()) ?>"></script>
<script src="js/socket.io.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

ical_parser.js

```
/** 
 * Javascript ical Parser
 * Proof of concept method of reading icalendar (.ics) files with javascript.
 *
 * @author: Carl Saggs
 * @source: https://github.com/thybag/
 * @version: 0.2
 */
function ical_parser(feed_url, callback){
    //store of unproccesed data.
    this.raw_data = null;
    //Store of proccessed data.
    this.events = [];

    /**
     * loadFile
     * Using AJAX to load the requested .ics file, passing it to the callback when completed.
     * @param url URL of .ics file
     * @param callback Function to call on completion.
     */
    this.loadFile = function(url, callback){
        //Create request object
        try {xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest(): new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}  catch (e) { }
        //Grab file
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
                //On success, run callback.
                callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }

    /**
     * makeDate
     * Convert the dateformat used by ICalendar in to one more suitable for javascript.
     * @param String ical_date 
     * @return dt object, includes javascript Date + day name, hour/minutes/day/month/year etc.
     */
    this.makeDate = function(ical_date){
        //break date apart
                var dtutc =  {
            year: ical_date.substr(0,4),
            month: ical_date.substr(4,2),
            day: ical_date.substr(6,2),
            hour: ical_date.substr(9,2),
            minute: ical_date.substr(11,2)
        }
        //Create JS date (months start at 0 in JS - don't ask)
                var utcdatems = Date.UTC(dtutc.year, (dtutc.month-1), dtutc.day, dtutc.hour, dtutc.minute);
                var dt = {};
                dt.date = new Date(utcdatems);

                dt.year = dt.date.getFullYear();
                dt.month = ('0' + (dt.date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
                dt.day = ('0' + dt.date.getDate()).slice(-2);
                dt.hour = ('0' + dt.date.getHours()).slice(-2);
                dt.minute = ('0' + dt.date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

        //Get the full name of the given day
        dt.dayname =["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][dt.date.getDay()];
                dt.monthname = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ][dt.date.getMonth()] ;

        return dt;
    }

    /**
     * parseICAL
     * Convert the ICAL format in to a number of javascript objects (Each representing a date)
     *
     * @param data Raw ICAL data
     */
    this.parseICAL = function(data){
        //Ensure cal is empty
        this.events = [];

        //Clean string and split the file so we can handle it (line by line)
        cal_array = data.replace(new RegExp( "\\r", "g" ), "").replace(/\n /g,"").split("\n");

        //Keep track of when we are activly parsing an event
        var in_event = false;
        //Use as a holder for the current event being proccessed.
        var cur_event = null;
        for(var i=0;i<cal_array.length;i++){
            ln = cal_array[i];
            //If we encounted a new Event, create a blank event object + set in event options.
            if(!in_event && ln == 'BEGIN:VEVENT'){
                in_event = true;
                cur_event = {};
            }
            //If we encounter end event, complete the object and add it to our events array then clear it for reuse.
                        if(in_event && ln == 'END:VEVENT'){
                in_event = false;
                this.events.push(cur_event);
                cur_event = null;
            }
            //If we are in an event
                        else if(in_event){
                                //var lntrim = ln.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
                                //var lnsplit = lntrim.split(':');
                                //type = lnsplit[0];
                                //val = lnsplit[1];

                //Split the item based on the first ":"
                idx = ln.indexOf(':');
                //Apply trimming to values to reduce risks of badly formatted ical files.
                type = ln.substr(0,idx).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');//Trim
                val = ln.substr(idx+1).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');

                //If the type is a start date, proccess it and store details
                if(type =='DTSTART'){
                    dt = this.makeDate(val);
                    val = dt.date;
                    //These are helpful for display
                    cur_event.start_time = dt.hour+':'+dt.minute;
                    cur_event.start_date = dt.day+'/'+dt.month+'/'+dt.year;
                    cur_event.day = dt.dayname;
                                        cur_event.start_date_long = dt.day+'. '+dt.monthname+' '+dt.year ;
                }
                //If the type is an end date, do the same as above
                                else if(type =='DTEND'){
                    dt = this.makeDate(val);
                    val = dt.date;
                    //These are helpful for display
                    cur_event.end_time = dt.hour+':'+dt.minute;
                    cur_event.end_date = dt.day+'/'+dt.month+'/'+dt.year;
                    cur_event.day = dt.dayname;
                }
                //Convert timestamp
                                else if(type =='DTSTAMP'){ 
                                        val = this.makeDate(val).date;
                                }
                                else {
                                    val = val
                                        .replace(/\\r\\n/g,'<br />')
                                        .replace(/\\n/g,'<br />')
                                        .replace(/\\,/g,',');
                                }

                //Add the value to our event object.
                cur_event[type] = val;
            }
        }
        //Run this to finish proccessing our Events.
        this.complete();
    }
    /**
     * complete
     * Sort all events in to a sensible order and run the original callback
     */
    this.complete = function(){
        //Sort the data so its in date order.
        this.events.sort(function(a,b){
            return a.DTSTART-b.DTSTART;
        });
        //Run callback method, if was defined. (return self)
        if(typeof callback == 'function') callback(this);
    }
    /**
     * getEvents
     * return all events found in the ical file.
     *
     * @return list of events objects
     */
    this.getEvents = function(){
        return this.events;
    }

    /**
     * getFutureEvents
     * return all events sheduled to take place after the current date.
     *
     * @return list of events objects
     */
    this.getFutureEvents = function(){
        var future_events = [], current_date = new Date();

        this.events.forEach(function(itm){
            //If the event ends after the current time, add it to the array to return.
            if(itm.DTEND > current_date) future_events.push(itm);
        });
        return future_events;
    }

    /**
     * getPastEvents
     * return all events sheduled to take place before the current date.
     *
     * @return list of events objects
     */
    this.getPastEvents = function(){
        var past_events = [], current_date = new Date();

        this.events.forEach(function(itm){
            //If the event ended before the current time, add it to the array to return.
            if(itm.DTEND <= current_date) past_events.push(itm);
        });
        return past_events.reverse();
    }

    /**
     * load
     * load a new ICAL file.
     *
     * @param ical file url
     */
    this.load = function(ical_file){
        var tmp_this = this;
        this.raw_data = null;
        this.loadFile(ical_file, function(data){
            //if the file loads, store the data and invoke the parser
            tmp_this.raw_data = data;
            tmp_this.parseICAL(data);
        });
    }

    //Store this so we can use it in the callback from the load function.
    var tmp_this = this;
    //Store the feed url
    this.feed_url = feed_url;
    //Load the file
    this.load(this.feed_url);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, I solved this Magic Mirror issue: http://michaelteeuw.nl/post/103473463837/fixing-the-magic-mirror-calendar